# Separate result for different date ranges

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to generate a report based on different date ranges. But the query that I have written is combining all results into one. Expecting to get 4 results for 4 date ranges.

PS: I am a beginner. Any help would be appreciated.

```
select
    sum(case when IsBlank = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as BlankChats,
    sum(case when LeadID > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ConvertedChats,
    sum(case when PickedUpBy != AssignedToAgent and AssignedToAgent > 0 and PickedUpBy > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as MissedChats,
    sum(case when AssignedToAgent > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as AssignedChats,
    sum(case when LeadType=1 then 1 else 0 end) as SalesLeads
from
    chats with (nolock)
    left join leads on leads.id=chats.leadid
where
    (chats.createdon >= DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and chats.createdOn <= DATEADD(MI, -1*30, GETDATE()))
OR
    (chats.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(d, -1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE())) and chats.createdOn <= DATEADD(MI, -1*30, DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE())))
OR
    (chats.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(d, -7, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE())) and chats.createdOn <= DATEADD(MI, -1*30, DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE())))
OR
    (chats.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(d, -8, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE())) and chats.createdOn <= DATEADD(MI, -1*30, DATEADD(d, -8, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: If you want 4 result sets you need to create 4 queries. And since you are just learning you might consider getting rid of that nolock hint before you get in the habit of littering your database with it. It does far more sinister things than simply dirty reads. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: please show sample result from your query and expected result

Comment: You may find it useful to add a date table to your db.  You can include a column, within that table, to group by.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 4 rows for your query, you will need to add the date ranges as a case statement to your select, then group by that case statement. You should then get a row per value created by your case - which in this case should be the date ranges you want the stats split by.